# virtualenvwrapper fails with "No module named Help2Man"

Tags: python, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to install virtualenvwrapper (4.7.2) on El Capitan using

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

This is a brew installed python/pip version (python 2.7.12, pip 8.1.2). The installation fails with

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named Help2Man
```

A help2man python module doesn't seem to exist anywhere, I could only find a command line tool with that name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this thanks to [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pbr/+bug/1624980). I had a package installed with invalid distutils.command entry points (in my case obspy 1.0.2 - this seems to be fixed in 1.0.3) which causes this error to pop-up in totally unrelated places.

I uninstalled obspy, installed virtualenvwrapper, then reinstalled obspy